# android studio 3.0.1 and kotlin v1.2.10-release-Studio3.0-1 got issue

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, kotlin

I am using android studio 3.0.1 and I was going to use Kotlin.

I wrote some simple code and when application runs the android studio shows me below error:

Error:Gradle:

> A problem occurred configuring root project 'Firstapp1'.
>   Could not resolve all files for configuration ':classpath'.
>   Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1.
>        Required by:
>            project :
>   Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1.
>   Could not parse POM https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.0.1/gradle-3.0.1.pom
>   Already seen doctype.

Gradle version: 4.1
Android plugin version : 3.0.1

[image]

Please help me to solve this problem!

Comment: You need to update the kotlin plugin by going to File > Settings > Plugins

Comment: Just make sure the version provided in Gradle and the plugin version installed are the same

Comment: thanks for response .my gradle version is 4.1 and the kotlin is v1.2.10-release-Studio3.0-1

Comment: everythings were updated.but still i have the problem

Comment: Change the version in gradle to v1.2.10

Comment: android plugin version is 3.0.1

Comment: how can i do the Change the version in gradle to v1.2.10  ?

Comment: Change the `ext.kotlin_version` attribute in the gradle

Comment: thanks .i'll do it and and tell the feedbak

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure the kotlin version used in gradle and the kotlin plugin version are the same like in the following snaps:
[image]

Version in gradle is 1.1.51

[image]

Version of the plugin installed is also 1.1.51

Answer (score 0):

i solved that problem.thanks.i have a new problem...

Error:Gradle: A problem occurred configuring root project 'Firstapp1'.

> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':classpath'.
>   Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1.
>        Required by:
>            project :
>   Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1.
>   Could not parse POM https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.0.1/gradle-3.0.1.pom
>   Already seen doctype.
>   Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1.
>   Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.0.1/gradle-3.0.1.pom'.
>   Could not HEAD 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.0.1/gradle-3.0.1.pom'.
>   Connect to jcenter.bintray.com:443 [jcenter.bintray.com/108.168.243.150] failed: Connection timed out: connect